# UIScrollView Pinch and Zoom ONLY on center?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

Been trying to figure this out for days.

Let's say I have an imageView embedded in a UISCrollView and everything is implemented correctly.

**How it is currently functioning:** When the user pinches and zooms on the top right of the image, it will zoom towards the top right area.
[image: Before]
[image: After pinching in top right of screen]

**How I want it:** I want the image to zoom ONLY on the center of the UIView, regardless on where the user pinches on the photo.

[image: Before]
[image: After pinching anywhere in the screen]

I was thinking of somehow intercepting the pinch gesture recognizer and modifying it so that the pinch locations are always in the center of the screen, but not sure if that's possible. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you want the zoom to happen only at centre, use **scrollViewDidZoom** delegate method.

**--CODE--**

```
-(void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    CGFloat width = scrollView.contentSize.width/2;
    width =width-width/scrollView.zoomScale;

    CGFloat height = scrollView.contentSize.height/2;
    height =height-height/scrollView.zoomScale;

    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(width, height);
}
```

Comment: Great piece of code! There's a bit more detail I need to add. I want the zoom to be centered where the black rectangle is centered, so if I pan to the top right and pinch, the new center of the black rectangle is on the top right. Regardless on where the user pinches, I want the picture to zoom towards the top right, which is the new center now. Also, I have some "contentInset" on the scrollView I need to account for.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, you have many options. I will state the one that I find the easiest (will delve deeper if it does not work).

Subclass the `UIScrollView` and override it's `layoutSubviews` method, and use it to set the `visibleRect` of the scroll view to the center of the scroll view (which happens to be the center of the image, judging by your screenshot). It will maintain it's `zoomLevel` so you do not need to alter it.

Comment: Thanks for replying! What property do I change for the scrollView in the layoutSubViews method? It doesn't seem like scrollView has a "visibleRect" property? Also, there's a bit more detail I need to add. I want the zoom to be centered where the black rectangle is centered, so if I pan to the top right and pinch, the new center of the black rectangle is on the top right. Regardless on where the user pinches, I want the picture to zoom towards the top right, which is the new center now.